# Cómo leer letras sin repetición?

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo hacer un programa un programa en java en un vector de tamaño n que solamente lea letras de la A ala j, que no se puedan repetir letras?

Adjunto mi intento

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            int n;
            n=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Cuantas letras introduciras: "));
            
            char[]letras=new char[n];
            for(char i=0;i<n;i++){
                letras[i]=(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Ingresa la letra: ").charAt(0));}
            
            for(char i=0;i<n;i++){
               
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Te faltó contarnos que problema tienes con este código. Por favor, ve a [edit] y amplía tu post, indicando claramente qué problema tienes, qué errores tienes, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel.

Acabo de leer tu pregunta y según entiendo, apartando el uso de Swing, lo que quieres es que dada una sucesión de caracteres te imprima únicamente letras que estén entre la A y la J y sin que haya repeticiones.

Si lo que me propones es eso, te propongo utilizar un HashSet para aquellas letras que ya hayas imprimido y por cada letra nueva por la que pasas compruebas si la letra está dentro del HashSet, si no lo contiene lo muestras y sino, no lo muestras, obviando, claro, que la letra debe estar entre la A y la J.

Si no he sido suficientemente claro, te adjunto código y espero que te pueda ayudar.

```java
import java.util.HashSet;

public class Ayuda {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sucesionDeCaracteres = "YXABCAAZYWXAADDDDEEEFFGHIJ";
        HashSet<Character> letrasYaImpresas = new HashSet();
        
        for(int i=0; i<sucesionDeCaracteres.length(); i++){
            Character letra = sucesionDeCaracteres.charAt(i);
            // Compruebo si la letra está en el rango propuesto y si no ha sido previamente mostrada por pantalla
            if(letra>='A' && letra<='J' && !letrasYaImpresas.contains(letra)){
                System.out.println(sucesionDeCaracteres.charAt(i));
            }
            // Añado la letra para que ya no se muestre más, si la letra ya estaba contenida,
            // por el tipo de estructura de datos que es el HashSet
            letrasYaImpresas.add(letra);
        }
    }
}
```